# How to display a child collection in VS Report Viewer 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a collection which is the datasource of the report.
And a object of that collection contains again a collection as a property.

How can i display this child collection in the report?

Tried to add the child collection as a second datasource. But i need values of the associated parent and child class for a calculation.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a subreport and filter the related data on the `SubreportProcessing` event.